# How to find the index of an element within JSON array (PostgreSQL 9.3)?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have some data in a table `radio responses` I am aggregating that looks like this:

```
SELECT question_id, arr FROM radio_responses;

  question_id |       arr       
-------------+-----------------
          73 | [1,0,0]
          73 | [1,0,0]
          73 | [0,1,0]
          73 | [0,1,0]
          73 | [0,1,0]
          73 | [0,0,1]
          73 | [0,1,0]
          73 | [0,1,0]
          73 | [0,0,1]
          73 | [0,0,1]
          73 | [1,0,0]
          74 | [1,0]
          74 | [0,1]
          74 | [1,0]
          74 | [0,1]
          74 | [1,0]
          74 | [0,1]
          77 | [0,1]
          77 | [0,1]
          77 | [0,1]
```

My end goal is to extract the index of the `1` from each array. I could not find any functions to do so with the JSON type, but I did find that I could do so with `idx()` if I have an `int[]` array.

I have tried various solutions, but they all seem to rely on unnesting the data first, which seems unnecessary, especially since information is lost in the process (unless there's something that uses `WITH ORDINALITY` that I missed).

I am using Postgres version 9.3.

Comment: `with t(x) as (values('[1,0,0]'::json)) select position('1' in translate(x::text,'[],','')) from t;`

Comment: This works for this particular case, but it does not work in the generalized sense, since it only looks for the `1` character, and not a particular value. E.g., if I had the first entry as `2010`, then it would return 3, because the third character of `2010` is `1`. Isn't there a way to extract the actual data as an array?

Comment: Sorry but I think you have got your database design completely wrong. You shouldn't be using JSON or Array here you should normalize your tables. You even have duplicates. `77 | [0,1]
          77 | [0,1]
          77 | [0,1]`

Comment: Those are deliberately duplicated elements, since they represent responses to questions (which will be counted/tabulated), and only the contents of the response and its associated question ID matter in this case(related data is stored elsewhere and is later joined). The reason for storing it in that format is because the JSON can be parsed very simply in Python, which is what the server is running. It is originally nested in a second level of a JSON array, but it was selectively extracted with another query.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Since you are not using array of ints, please change your example to fit the real use case.

Comment: It's in a JSON format. The original array looks something like

`[[2000],[1,0,0],[0,1],[12],[1,1,0]]` in each row, and I expanded it with a cross join and used a `->` operator to extract the value of the ones that correspond to a specific question type. The resulting data from that operation is still JSON.

Comment: I think that JSON is the wrong choice for this. You should be storing that as a native (integer) array. That will be a much more efficient and a lot easier to handle (assuming that all that the JSON document stores is the array and some kind of ID). You might want to read this: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Answer (score 2):

```
select      *
          ,(select min(i) + 1
            from   generate_series(0,json_array_length(arr)-1) as gs (i)
            where  (arr->>i)::int = 1
            )                           as ind

from        radio_responses
;
```

---

```
+-------------+---------+-----+
| question_id | arr     | ind |
+-------------+---------+-----+
| 73          | [1,0,0] | 1   |
+-------------+---------+-----+
| 73          | [1,0,0] | 1   |
+-------------+---------+-----+
| 73          | [0,1,0] | 2   |
+-------------+---------+-----+
| 73          | [0,1,0] | 2   |
+-------------+---------+-----+
| 73          | [0,1,0] | 2   |
+-------------+---------+-----+
| 73          | [0,0,1] | 3   |
+-------------+---------+-----+
| 73          | [0,1,0] | 2   |
+-------------+---------+-----+
| 73          | [0,1,0] | 2   |
+-------------+---------+-----+
| 73          | [0,0,1] | 3   |
+-------------+---------+-----+
| 73          | [0,0,1] | 3   |
+-------------+---------+-----+
| 73          | [1,0,0] | 1   |
+-------------+---------+-----+
| 74          | [1,0]   | 1   |
+-------------+---------+-----+
| 74          | [0,1]   | 2   |
+-------------+---------+-----+
| 74          | [1,0]   | 1   |
+-------------+---------+-----+
| 74          | [0,1]   | 2   |
+-------------+---------+-----+
| 74          | [1,0]   | 1   |
+-------------+---------+-----+
| 74          | [0,1]   | 2   |
+-------------+---------+-----+
| 77          | [0,1]   | 2   |
+-------------+---------+-----+
| 77          | [0,1]   | 2   |
+-------------+---------+-----+
| 77          | [0,1]   | 2   |
+-------------+---------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question actually is not about RDBMS. However if you don't want to use unnesting and so on and if you stuck on the 9.3 version:

```
create or replace function json_array_position(a json, e int) returns int language plpythonu stable as $$
  import json;
  r = json.loads(a)
  return r.index(e)
$$;

select json_array_position('[1,2,3]'::json, 2);
```